# Using a Django profile field to restrict queryset of a list view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I want to use a field in the Profile model of a logged in user to restrict the queryset used in a Django class based view.

My models are:

```
# User profile info
class Profile(models.Model):

    # Relationship Fields
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.ForeignKey('eduly.School', default=1)

    notes = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

and

```
class School(models.Model):

    # Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    contactName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.slug

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('eduly_school_detail', args=(self.slug,))


    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('eduly_school_update', args=(self.slug,))


class Teacher(models.Model):

    SCHOOL_ADMIN = 0
    CLASS_ADMIN = 1
    TASK_ADMIN = 2

    ROLES = {
        (SCHOOL_ADMIN, "School administrator"),
        (CLASS_ADMIN, "Class administrator"),
        (TASK_ADMIN, "Task administrator")
    }

    # Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    roles = models.IntegerField("Role", choices=ROLES, default=1)

    # Relationship Fields
    school = models.ForeignKey('eduly.School', )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('eduly_teacher_detail', args=(self.slug,))


    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('eduly_teacher_update', args=(self.slug,))
```

The view whose queryset I am trying to restrict is:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class TeacherListView(ListView):
    model = Teacher

    def get_queryset(self):
            return Teacher.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

But instead of `return Teacher.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)` I want to only list Teachers who have a `school` the same as the `school` in the logged in user's `Profile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this would work:

```
Teacher.objects.filter(school=self.request.user.profile.school)
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't seem to be related to this question.

Comment: Turns out I needed to add template_name = "eduly/teacher_list.html" above the get_queryset(self). With no get_queryset I don't need a template_name. The filter is returning an empty query though.